# List of Acronyms

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am writing my thesis in `LaTeX`. I need to create a list of acronyms (or abbreviations).

I want to have a page like what I have for list of tables and list of figures in which I specify all the acronyms I have used in my thesis.

Is there any way by which I can create such a list?

The class that I have used is:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,oneside,final]{book}
```

I have used following methods which none of them works,

```
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
% abbreviations:
\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
```

and the second method is,

```
\usepackage[toc,section=section]{glossaries}

\newglossary{abbrev}{abs}{abo}{List of Abbreviations}
\newglossaryentry{MS}{
    name        = MS ,
    description = mass spectroscopy ,
    type        = abbrev
}

\makeglossaries
```

Comment: `\printacronyms` does not work? ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Either use `printacronyms` for the regular `acronyms` or `\printglossary[type=abbrev]` for the self-defined `abbrev` glossary.

In order to be on the safe side about **all** acronyms, use `\glsaddall` in the document body.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,oneside,final]{book}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
% abbreviations:
\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}


\newglossary{abbrev}{abs}{abo}{List of Abbreviations}
\newglossaryentry{MS}{
    name        = MS ,
    description = mass spectroscopy ,
    type        = abbrev
}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}


\gls{ny}

\gls{MS}

\printacronyms

\printglossary[type=abbrev]

\end{document}
```

Don't forgot to use the external `makeglossaries` script (or use `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossary[type=abbrev]`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I got the same error! it tells me "line 46: File `mfirstuc.sty' not found. \RequirePackage". when I refer to this line it says "\RequirePackage{textcase}". So, it does not work! Do you have any idea on what the problem is?

Comment: @user101587: You apparently have some missing packages, that's the error!

Comment: I copied the exact code but I didn't get the same result?!

Comment: @F505: Well, what do you expect me to do then?

Comment: What if I want define acronyms in the text and add them automatically to the acronyms list? Is there a way I can use some command that can add all definitions inside text and it generates the acronyms list (like it happens with sections added in the table of contents)?

Comment: @DaltonCézane: `\glsaddall` is the command you're looking for

Comment: It did not work. I would like to define the acronyms when they appear in the text. For instance: "this is some text with this AHTBA (Acronym Here To Be Added)." I want some way I can use some command that automatically add this `AHTBA (Acronym Here To Be Added)` to the acronyms list. I searched a bit, but I did not find something related to that.

Comment: @DaltonCézane: That doesn't work with `glossaries`, at least not that way and is not recommended anyway. The `\newglossaryentry` or `\newacronym` is the path to pursue, i.e. defining the entries beforehand such that you can reuse it in any other file. In-text-definitions are not really useful.

Comment: If it was possible, it would help with the "list of abbreviations" in a thesis document. Now, we have to add each abbreviation manually at that list, what is a boring process. Thank you, anyway.